# Xamarin Flickering screen

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I am trying to add a fading effect to my background color, so I created this code:

```
public GetStartedPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    new Task(() => { Animation(); }).Start();
}

private async void Animation()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await this.ColorTo(Color.FromHex("#212121"), Color.FromHex("#5e5e5e"), c => this.BackgroundColor = c, 3000);
        await this.ColorTo(Color.FromHex("#5e5e5e"), Color.FromHex("#212121"), c => this.BackgroundColor = c, 3000);
    }
}
```

With this extension:

```
public static class ViewExtensions
{
    public static Task<bool> ColorTo(this VisualElement self, Color fromColor, Color toColor, Action<Color> callback, uint length = 250, Easing easing = null)
    {
        Func<double, Color> transform = (t) =>
            Color.FromRgba(fromColor.R + t * (toColor.R - fromColor.R),
                            fromColor.G + t * (toColor.G - fromColor.G),
                            fromColor.B + t * (toColor.B - fromColor.B),
                            fromColor.A + t * (toColor.A - fromColor.A));
        return ColorAnimation(self, "ColorTo", transform, callback, length, easing);
    }

    public static void CancelAnimation(this VisualElement self)
    {
        self.AbortAnimation("ColorTo");
    }

    static Task<bool> ColorAnimation(VisualElement element, string name, Func<double, Color> transform, Action<Color> callback, uint length, Easing easing)
    {
        easing = easing ?? Easing.Linear;
        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        element.Animate<Color>(name, transform, callback, 16, length, easing, (v, c) => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(c));
        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

When I do this, the screen just starts to flicker, but with no smooth fading....

Why is this and how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you targeting a specific platform or it happens on all of them?

Comment: I am deploying on Android, so Android :)

Comment: Try to use `Easing.CubicOut`, here are several Easing types https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.easing.cubicin?view=xamarin-forms  You can try to run your applcation in the android device as well, please do not run it in you emulator, android emulator will dropped frames.

Comment: Where should I put that?

Comment: please change from  `easing = easing ?? Easing.Linear;` to easing = easing ??Easing.CubicOut``  in `ColorAnimation` method.

Comment: Still flickering!?

Comment: Did you test it in the Android device or emulator？